# Identify and extract URLs from text corpus

Tags: python, regex, natural-language-processing

I'm working on a project that requires POS Tagging of paragraphs. The text contains lot of URLs which contain various punctuation marks such as `.` `?`.  This affects the accuracy of the sentence tokenization.

So I decided to clean the data by removing/replacing all the URLs. And thought regular expressions would be handy in doing that. Remember, I want to match not just the domain name but the complete URL.

For example, in the below text,

```
Hey Mayur, We have successfully credited the cashback amount of INR 600 in your CITRUS wallet linked to mobile - 9130977755. Please download and rate our apps here - http://smarturl.it/ixigoapps Happy travelling! Team ixigo
```

I want the regex to match `http://smarturl.it/ixigoapps`

Here's what I came up with so far

```
https?:\/\/?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&=\/]*
```

Right now, I'm not concerned about protocols other than `http` and `https`, but I would like to match URLs without `http` or `https` but start with `www`. Example: `www.acttv.in`

What do you think of my approach so far, and the regular expression?

Comment: See also: https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex

Comment: @RichardNeumann Because they're using [tag:python]'s regex engine. [@close-voters this question is on-topic](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2562).

Comment: @RichardNeumann, thanks for the link. I'm testing few of them out with my text corpus.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered:

```
re.compile('(www|http)\S+')
```

I tested it on your example string and it worked well (for both `www` and `http`). This does assume your links are likely to be links, and your data is fairly clean/consistent.